# Почему при наложении (вставке) цветной картинки на картинку градиента серого в итоге обе картинки получаются серого градиента: pillow python?

Tags: python, pillow

Пытаюсь наложить одну картинку на другую через метод paste библиотеки pillow. Одну из картинок обрабатываю методом convert("L"), сохраняю под другим именем. Далее беру другую картинку (уже цветную) и через paste вставляю в первую, которая уже в градациях серого. В итоге результат получаю целиком черно-белый, а хотелось бы на сером фоне получить цветное изображение

```
with Image.open(filename) as img:
    img.load()
    img.show() # здесь изображение цветное

with Image.open(filename_2) as img_auto:
    img_auto.load()
    gray_image = img_auto.filter(ImageFilter.BoxBlur(7))
    gray_image_1 = gray_image.convert("L")
    gray_image_1.show() # здесь изображение в градациях серого
    gray_image_1.save(filename_3)

with Image.open(filename_3) as img_auto2:
    img_auto2.convert('RGB')
    img_auto2.paste(img, (50, 0), mask=img)
    img_auto2.show()   # здесь результат полностью черно-белый, а нужен серый фон и 
                         поверх цветная картинка
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
img_auto2.convert('RGB')
```

Вы совершенно правильно преобразовываете ч/б изображение обратно в цветное, это должно сработать, но вы не сохраняете никуда результат. Надо сохранять результат так же, как вы выше это делаете с ч/б картинкой, например, в ту же самую переменную:

```py
img_auto2 = img_auto2.convert('RGB')
```